New column in R data table via function that looks up in other data table
I have a data.table and want to add a new column:
big_table[, ("new_column") := some_function( col1, col2, … ) ]

The function may be defined as
some_function <- function( xCol1, xCol2, …  ){
      result <- small_table[col1 %in% xCol1 & col2 %in% xCol2 & …)] [, paste0("some_text_", xCol1), with=FALSE ][[1]]

# or, alternatively
      result <- small_table[col1 %in% xCol1 & col2 %in% xCol2 & …)] [[, paste0("some_text_", xCol1)]]

     return( result )
    }

This function looks for the variable column paste0("some_text_", xCol1) in small_table, where, due to the filter, only one row exists.
The function itself is working fine if called once. But the use in adding a new column to big_table fails.
With the first line in the definition of the function I get an error
Error in ` big_table[, ("new_column") := some_function( col1 : 
  Supplied 588 items to be assigned to 116588 items of column 'new_column'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

With the alternative code I get
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2

I guess the variable look up in small_table causes the problem, can anyone please help me to fix that?

Simple example to explain the problem:
supplement <- data.table(code = c("male", "female"),
                         child = c(1, 2),
                         adult = c(3, 4))

DT <- data.table(A = c("male1", "male2", "male3", "female1", "female2"),
                 B = c("child", "child", "adult", "adult", "child"))

desired_result <- data.table(A = c("male1", "male2", "male3", "female1", "female2"),
                             B = c("child", "child", "adult", "adult", "child"),
                             sup = c("1", "1", "3", "4", "2"))


Hello. Some sample data and expected result would help a lot. You can provide them using dput function

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Just added a simple example

It seems to me that you don't need any calculations here, just a merge statement if you prepare your data slightly differently.
# extract sex
DT[, sex := gsub("[0-9]+", "", A)]
print(DT)

         A      B    sex
    <char> <char> <char>
1:   male1  child   male
2:   male2  child   male
3:   male3  adult   male
4: female1  adult female
5: female2  child female

# reframe supplement
sup_long <- data.table::melt(
    supplement,
    id.vars = "code",
    value.name = "sup"
)
print(sup_long)

     code variable   sup
   <char>   <fctr> <num>
1:   male    child     1
2: female    child     2
3:   male    adult     3
4: female    adult     4

# merge the two together
result <- merge(
    DT,
    sup_long,
    by.x = c("sex", "B"),
    by.y = c("code", "variable"),
    sort = FALSE,
    all.x = TRUE
)

# keep only desired columns
result <- result[, .(A, B, sup)]
print(result)

         A      B   sup
    <char> <char> <num>
1:   male1  child     1
2:   male2  child     1
3:   male3  adult     3
4: female1  adult     4
5: female2  child     2


Obviously the best solution to my problem, thanks a lot, As I obtained the supplement data with a dcast, it is quite natural to melt it down again.
